# Microservice design

Tags: validation, microservices

We have a product where 4 microservices are communicating with each other.
Let's say entry point receives a payload as below:

```
{
  "Employees": [
    {
      "userId": "rirani",
      "jobTitleName": "Developer",
      "firstName": "Romin",
      "lastName": "Irani",
      "preferredFullName": "Romin Irani",
      "employeeCode": "E1",
      "region": "CA",
      "phoneNumber": "408-1234567",
      "emailAddress": "romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

The 1st microservice does validation on the payload "employeeCode" it allows only employee code which. starts with "E" else returns 400 status code. The Same payload is forwarded to other componet as well if  all validation passes.

Now my question is tomorrow there could be fair chance that external service consumes our any of the components to process their request. Do we need to have the validation in all the components?

Now there is no external client which uses our components but in the future maybe.
It's a more of a design question. Do we need to make our validation as a jar or we should not duplicate the validation itself? Its client responsibility to send the correct data if they are calling any other component except Microservice-1.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Every service which exposes a boundary is responsible for what passes that boundary. You cannot assume that the caller will always validate that they are passing the correct data.

Comment: What is the reason for splitting the processing of the employees into 4 separate Microservices? Or is this just an example? Can you illustrate what the other Microservices are doing?